# Display div if category has a specific parent

Tags: php, woocommerce-offtopic

I have a PHP snippet that displays a div on product pages based on their specific category ID.

How can I adapt this code to display the div based on whether the category is an ancestor of a specific parent?

I'd like to take a more blanket approach as opposed to singling out specific IDs if possible - here's what I've been using so far (thank you in advance for any help):

```
function options_available() {
global $product;
global $post;
$terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'product_cat' );
foreach ($terms as $term) {
    $product_cat_id = $term->term_id;
    break;
}
if ($product_cat_id == "54" || $product_cat_id == "84" || $product_cat_id == "2022" || $product_cat_id == "56" || $product_cat_id == "972" || $product_cat_id == "55" || $product_cat_id == "62" || $product_cat_id == "63" || $product_cat_id == "2024" || $product_cat_id == "2023" || $product_cat_id == "61" || $product_cat_id == "2210" || $product_cat_id == "2253" ) {
   echo '<div class="fkrow"> </div>';
}
```

Comment: When you say ancestor, can the category be a grandchild, or are you only targeting children?

Comment: Hi Jacob - I'm trying to target products within subcategories of a specific parent(s) - I've found a (potentially clunky) solution, which I'll add below.

Answer (score 0):

So effectively, I'm now able to  set a parent category ID, and have all the products that exist in subcategories within that parent ID echo my desired content - definitely open to any suggestions or improvements here!

I'm using this in a function, which is placing the 'tt' div on my target product pages in a specified place (depending on priority).

The foreach loop is pulling category IDs, then checking the resulting $term against a parent ID stipulated in the if statement (60 in this case).

```
function test($term) {
    global $product;
    global $post;
    $terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'product_cat' );
    
    foreach ($terms as $term) {
    $product_cat_id = $term->term_id;
    if ( $term->parent == 60 ) 
    {
        echo '<div class="tt">test</div>';}
    }
}
```